# Autofocus for text box for non modal view

Tags: html, angularjs

I've found out recently you are able to use autofocus: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp

As a nice, user friendly way of when clicking onto a modal view it will immediately allow said user to type in the box. However a section of my applications resolves around when clicking on a button it will then send you to another page as opposed to the modal.

```
<label for="name" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label no-padding-right"> Name</label>
 <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
    <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" autofocus ng-model="targetEntity.name" placeholder="Name" value=" {{targetEntity.name}}" ng-maxlength="128">
    <p ng-show="testDetailsForm.name.$invalid && !testDetailsForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Mandatory field, maximum length 128 characters.</p>
</div>
```

I applied autofocus to the value I would like to have it, however it didn't seem to work unlike the modal views. Therefore, I'm wondering is it possible to have autofocus for a seperate new page as opposed to a modal on top of an existing one.

Comment: If you read the page you linked it states the following: `When present, it specifies that an <input> element should automatically get focus when the page loads.` Meaning: It only works on page load. If it's in a modal view you have to set the focus via Javascript on your own.

Comment: Hello, would you have a link to something I could use to achieve that?

Comment: You can use [.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus) to focus an element.